# Скрипт поисковой системы

Tags: search, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста скрипт поисковой системы(которая парсит результаты с гугла, яндекса, яхуу и тому подобных поисковикой), желательно что бы поиск был так же и по фотографиям. Сколь лазила  нечего дельного не нашла.Заранее спасибо!

Comment: руки в помощь, пишите сами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы никогда и не найдёте такую! Есть поисковик на **PHP** + **MySQL** и называется он **Sphider**, не самый умный и быстрый, зато бесплатный. То, что просите вы - сделать в принципе можно, но за очень приличные деньги.